# mysql infile convert string to time format

Tags: mysql, sql, time, load-data-infile

I have a TSV that I'm trying to infile into a mySQL table.  A couple columns are time formats, but they don't match the standard time format of `HH:MM:SS`, instead they look like `HH:MM AM/PM`

I've seen examples to do this with PHP, but I was hoping there was a way to do with with mysql `str_to_date`

Here's what I've worked up so far.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 
'C:\\SINGLE_PROP\\open_houses.txt' 
REPLACE INTO TABLE singleprop.jos_openhouse 
IGNORE 1 LINES
SET OHSSTARTTM = STR_TO_DATE('%g:%i %a', '%g:%i:%s');
```

I keep getting an incorrect time format error.  Here's how the table looks.

```
CREATE TABLE `jos_openhouse` (
  `OHSSTARTDT` DATE NOT NULL,
  `OHSHOSTBID` varchar(14) NOT NULL,
  `OHSMLSNO` int(7) NOT NULL,
  `OHSSTARTTM` TIME NOT NULL,
  `OHSENDTM'` TIME NOT NULL,
  `OHSREMARK` TEXT,
  `OHSTYPE` TEXT,
  `OHSUPDTDT` TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`OHSMLSNO`))
ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Should the column be created as 'TEXT' first so infile can put the data there and then it's converted to time format after it's been imported?

Comment: You should only create `TEXT` columns for things that cannot fit in a `VARCHAR` column, for instance things that are over 255 characters long. A date this long is surely invalid.

Comment: Remark is a description with charcter length 500 ;)

Comment: You can always declare a `VARCHAR(512)` in newer versions of MySQL. Since `TEXT` columns are stored in a separate blob area of the database, their performance is usually terrible. `VARCHAR` is stored in the row itself.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('11:15 PM', '%h:%i %p') ;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
TIME
--------
23:15:00
```

Try this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 
'C:\\SINGLE_PROP\\open_houses.txt' 
REPLACE INTO TABLE singleprop.jos_openhouse (col1, col2, ..., @OHSSTARTTM)
IGNORE 1 LINES
SET OHSSTARTTM = STR_TO_DATE(@OHSSTARTTM, '%h:%i %p');
```

Comment: So, I have have to put in what the string looks like, even if the string value is different for each entry?

Comment: You have change your columnname of text file with 11:15 PM

Comment: You show it what it looks like, then when it translates to.  Not what is in sytax to what it should be.  ...if that makes sense. :)

Comment: so are you putting all the columns uploaded in that bracket?

Comment: I get `ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION singleprop.STR_TO_TIME does not exist`.  'STR_TO_TIME' isn't a thing.

Comment: You have to add all table columns of table which in sequence of file columns and put this variable for column with @ohsstarttm.

Answer (score 1):

```
 SET OHSSTARTTM = STR_TO_DATE('%g:%i %a', '%g:%i:%s');
```

consider

> [TIME()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time)

since u usingtime

Comment: Trying to alter the string to be in TIME format. Not what I'm looking for but thanks!